# Why mutable.Set.empty ++= treeSet instead of ++?

Tags: scala, collections, mutable

While reading the book "Programming in Scala 3/e", I have fallen to the following question.

First, the book explains that in order to create a mutable set from an immutable set, write the code as:

```
scala> import scala.collections.immutable.TreeSet
scala> val colors = List("blue", "green", "red")
scala> val treeSet = TreeSet(colors)
scala> val mutaSet = mutable.Set.empty ++= treeSet
    -> mutaSet: scala.collection.mutable.Set[String] =
       Set(red, blue, green, yellow)
scala> val immutaSet = Set.empty ++ mutaSet
    -> immutaSet: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] =
       Set(red, blue, green, yellow)
```

What I can't understand is the use of `++=` method in the following line:

```
val mutaSet = mutable.Set.empty ++= treeSet
```

According to [the Scala reference](https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_7.html), it says that when we write `xs ++= ys`, it adds all elements of `ys` to `xs` and return the value of `xs`, i.e. there is a side effect when we call the `++=` method.

However in order for this explanation to be valid, `mutable.Set.empty` has to be a lvalue or something, i.e. it is not a constant value. But I don't think so.

Can anyone explain why we `mutable.Set.empty ++= treeSet` is a valid expression?

Comment: Why do you think that `mutable.Set.empty` is a constant ? `mutable.Set.empty` is actually a function which returns a new empty set. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/mutable/Set$.html#empty[A]:scala.collection.mutable.Set[A]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm still confused with the concept of lvalues and rvalues. In Scala, can function-generated values be assigned a value? And in this case, why do we use `++=` instead of `++`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it says that when we write xs ++= ys, it adds all elements of ys to xs and return the value of xs

If there is a `++=` method, it just calls this method. And that's what happens here because [there is such a method for `collection.mutable.Set`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/mutable/Set.html#++=(xs:scala.collection.TraversableOnce[A]):Growable.this.type).

In case there is no such method, `xs` would indeed need to be a variable (though "return the value of `xs`" should be replaced by "assigns the result to `xs`").

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between `++` and `++=` methods is that first one create new collection but the second one just adds elements from `treeSet` to set. if you need to use mutable collections there is no sense to create new collection each time. For example:

```
val treeSet = collection.immutable.TreeSet(1,2)
val mSet = collection.mutable.Set.empty[Int]
mSet ++ treeSet // creates new Set(1, 2) and doesn't change mSet
println(mSet) // Set()
mSet ++= treeSet // adds to mSet all elements from treeSet
println(mSet) // Set(1, 2)
```

So, the answer - yes, `++=` is valid